# How do i view queries being executed by my mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I keep on seeing this in my log/development.log, and I am wondering whether this query is actually being executed in my database:

```
MONGODB (0ms) socialcrunch_development['tags'].find({:_id=>"secrets"}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
```

Ho can I see the queries being executed on my mongo db, so I can count them, should they all typically be .find commands, or should i being looking for something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Print all active reads:

```
db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(
   function(d){
     if(d.waitingForLock && d.lockType != "read")
        printjson(d)
     })
```

Print all active writes:

```
db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(
   function(d){
     if(d.waitingForLock && d.lockType != "write")
        printjson(d)
     })
```

You can get a lot more granular if you like by using `currentOp.op` to filter by a specific operation type (insert, update, delete, etc).

Check out the following page from MongoDB.org's documentation for more info:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/current-op/

Comment: This hits high on my google search, I was looking for something similar as to mysql `SET global general_log = 1;SET global log_output = 'table';` and then querying the queries made by my application (maybe even filter by query text). This helped me out with mysql in a great way to see what my application is actually querying but have no idea how to do this in mongodb and googling for it gets me to pages similar as this one to look for active queries.

Comment: @HMR currentOp is just what it sounds like (only the current operations). If you're looking to collect all database activity from your application so that you can analyze your query performance there's a related but different tool for that. Try setting the profile level to "2" which logs everything to the system.profile collection. More info here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: Note that you don't want to leave the profile level on like that all the time. Only run it like that for a short period of time, then disable it. Profiling that heavily does incur a performance cost and extra writes.