# Mongo Monitoring tool

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, process-monitoring

Is there any tool that exists for monitoring mongo?  Lets say for example we want to take a peek and see a list of queries executing against the database in order to see how they are performing.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: As per query analysis: this shouls be done manually using the `.explain()` method. As per the question on how to monitor MongoDB, it rather belongs to https://dba.stackexchange.com Please delete your question here before posting there - double posts are frowned upon. Big time ;)

Comment: having some trouble deleting this

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if these are the links you are looking for but I have a found a couple of things which might help you:

Another monitoring question on MongoDB
[MongoDB Monitoring question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970227/how-do-i-view-queries-being-executed-by-my-mongodb)

A MongoDB University class might be useful:

[MongoDB University 312](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M312/about)

Some Documentation on MongoDB:

[MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/free-monitoring/)

[More MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/)

I'm not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: Instead of just linking, you should at least provide a gist of what is covered in the links. If the links change, your answer becomes pretty much useless ;)

Comment: I know your right I thought about it after.. Also I was in a rush so I meant to edit it later but I forgot